# Exception handling best practices in C#

Tags: c#, exception

I have a question regarding handling exceptions redundantly in the calling method and called method. Consider the following example:

```
protected void method1(string action)
{
  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(action))
  {
    throw new ArgumentException("action cannot be null or empty or white space.");
  }
  //do something
}

public void method2(string name, string action)
{
  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
  {
    throw new ArgumentException("name cannot be null or empty or whitespace.");
  }
   method1(action);
  //do something
}
```

In the above example, should I also check for action to be null in method2 ? I feel that since it is handled in the method1, I don't have to deal with it as it might result in redundant code.

Any suggestions would be of great help in learning about the exception handling best practices. Thanks

Comment: Probably needs to be closed as opinion-based, but I would say if the only method that breaks if `action` is null is `method1` then _that_ is where the exception should be raised.  I wouldn't consider it "wrong" if `method2` didn't check for that as well, though.

Comment: Depends on whether `method1` is `private` or `public`, so if `method2` is the public entry-method it can serve as pre-check method for the private `method1`. Nitpick: you check for `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` but the error message is "action cannot be null".

Comment: see here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seyhszts(v=vs.100).aspx also search in google you will find lot of resources

Comment: it depends on what do you want, But you can take a look at Null Object Design Pattern , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern Or https://dotnetcodr.com/2013/05/06/design-patterns-and-practices-in-net-the-null-object-pattern/ . BTW, in this example I prefer to throw an exception In method 1 and handle it in Method 2

Comment: @DStanley I think its more than opinion based. My question is not what one feels about this, but what is the best/recommended practice.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I have updated the access specifier based on my current concern.

Answer (score 2):

If your `method1` is a `private` / `internal` implementation of `method2` and is only be invoked by `method2` then you don't need to place argument guard on both methods.

Comment: what if method1 is not private or internal.  It looks like that might be the case here

Comment: When this answer was posted, both the methods were `private` in the OP because they didn't have any qualifiers.

Comment: @MatthewWatson They also didn't have a return type either, so you could tell that the full method signature simply wasn't there.

Answer (score -2):

I always check. I know how the code works *now*, but I don't have any idea what it will do in the future. The code will change; by my hand or someone else's. Code that doesn't check is a time-bomb waiting to explode.

Comment: To be fair, it _is_ being checked; the question is _where_ should it be checked.

Comment: It's hard to tell what the OP's use case is, but on the surface, It looks like `method2` might just another way to call `method1` with a different set of parameters.  If that is the case, I'd say your answer is wrong, and you should strive to keep method2 as free of logic as you possibly can

Comment: I have to disagree once again. You are right, right now. The problem is when someone else comes along and changes something. You always have to code defensively for the future; because you wrote it, and we all know that the person who wrote it always gets the blame regardless of who actually broke it.